# Error in importing a file in different folder and how to access a variable from the file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, operating-system

I have two folders , for my Transmitter and Reciever. I have a folder structure lets say `/home/ubuntu/pf/basic/transmitter` under which i have a file `encode.py` . It has a variable `encoder` which i want to access from the folder `/home/ubuntu/pf/basic/reciever/helper/decoder` in the file `estimator.py` The `estimator.py` is imported in the `main.py` . 
So i tried using previous discussion to add the following in `estimator.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/ubuntu/pf/basic/reciever/helper/decoder')
```

It however complains that therew is no module ? IS there another way of importing variables in a file in python ?

And how I can i access the variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: apparently you added the wrong path, if you want to import encode.py you should add its path not the one for other script, i.e you should change your code to:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/ubuntu/pf/basic/transmitter')
import encode  # or from encode import encoder
```

also you have some other options, you can use sys.path.append:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/pf/basic/transmitter')
import encode  # or from encode import encoder
```

also you can put encode.py in same folder with estimator.py

or you can add '/home/ubuntu/pf/basic/transmitter' to your os environmental variables